# changing password directly possible?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I will change my password, because I realize that is in use for another account too. Can I do it myself somehow or must I do this over [reset-password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- select your user on top screen
- select "edit my profile & setting" ("setting" if on meta)
- select "My Logins"
- there is a "change password" link under "Stack exchange" line